# Getting ArrayMemoryError while exporting a big CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

I am trying to write and export a big CSV file but getting the following error "numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.85 GiB for an array with shape (651219361,) and data type object"

The CSV file which I am importing has about 1,400,000 rows and the output is going to get a lot for example when I am importing a file with 100 rows I am getting 2,400 rows of output.

Is there any way I can Export the CSV file without crashing?

**The Code of my program is:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

patents = pd.read_csv('E:/Work/final.csv')

patents = patents[['publn_nr', 'permno_adj', 'publn_year', 'IPC1']].dropna().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
patents = patents[(patents['publn_year'] >= 1980) & (patents['publn_year'] < 2016)].reset_index(drop=True)
patents['permno_adj'] = patents['permno_adj'].astype(str) + patents['publn_year'].astype(str)
print(patents.head())

patents = patents.groupby(['permno_adj', 'IPC1'])['publn_nr'].nunique().reset_index()
patents.columns = ['permno_adj', 'IPC1', 'ipc_patents']

patents['total_patents'] = patents.groupby(['permno_adj'])['ipc_patents'].transform('sum')
patents['share'] = patents['ipc_patents'] / patents['total_patents']

for v in ['IPC1']:

    temp = patents.copy()

    T = temp.pivot(index='%s' % v, columns='permno_adj', values='share')
    T = T.fillna(0)

    X_t = temp.pivot(index='permno_adj', columns='%s' % v, values='share')
    X_t = X_t.fillna(0)

    T_t = T.copy()
    for column in list(T_t):
        T_t[column] = T_t[column] / (np.sqrt(np.dot(T_t[[column]].values.T, T_t[[column]].values)[0][0],))

    om_f = X_t.T.dot(X_t)
    om_s = X_t.T.dot(X_t)

    for sic1 in list(om_s):
        for sic2 in list(om_s):
            om_s.loc[sic1][sic2] = om_s.loc[sic1][sic2] / (np.sqrt(om_f[sic1][sic1]) * np.sqrt(om_f[sic2][sic2]))

    tech = T_t.T.dot(om_s).dot(T_t)

    tech = tech.unstack().reset_index(level=1)

    if 'IPC1' in v:
        tech.columns = ['permno_adj_pat', 'tech_mahal_sim']

    tech = tech.reset_index()

    tech = tech[(tech['permno_adj'] != tech['permno_adj_pat'])].sort_values(
        ['permno_adj', 'permno_adj_pat']).reset_index(drop=True)

    if 'IPC1' in v:
        tech.to_csv('gajuf.csv')
        print(done)
```

**The full error I am getting is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Work\SMS London PPT by Gaju Masare\python work\sic_tech_only.py", line 41, in <module>
    tech = tech.unstack().reset_index(level=1)
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 317, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1584, in reset_index
    return df.reset_index(
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 317, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6349, in reset_index
    level_values = algorithms.take(
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 1565, in take
    result = take_nd(
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\array_algos\take.py", line 117, in take_nd
    return _take_nd_ndarray(arr, indexer, axis, fill_value, allow_fill)
  File "C:\Users\Gaju\PycharmProjects\first project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\array_algos\take.py", line 156, in _take_nd_ndarray
    out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype, order="F")
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.85 GiB for an array with shape (651219361,) and data type object
```

**The Output looks something like this:**
[image]

Comment: you can use chunks while reading csv to takle memory error.

Comment: I assume you can see the problem is not with the CSV file, the problem is the unstacking.  Isn't there a way you can write the CSV rows without creating that temporary array?